I have accidentally sent SOL to an NFT address. Is it impossible to get it bacK?
This is the transaction ID of me sending 10+ SOL to a NFT address...:
https://solscan.io/tx/2sVsnvgvTTNaSm3Xk5N9aKhoihDbWCqrrLfJC7UfjjhR4qsRUNqNvrBGA8xtCCtGMPzXak2ZHhYkuRV8z9phWxiL
